# Chromium 113 with proxy, can't figure out the way to use my proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, chromium, http-proxy

I use Linux Mint.

If I run:

```
chromium --proxy-server="https=localhost:8000;http=localhost:8000"
```

or

```
chromium --proxy-server="localhost:8000"
```

There's no use of my proxy.

**I know my proxy works, because I can use it as a charm with Firefox**, or:

```
curl --proxy http://localhost:8000 https://ipinfo.io/ip
```

I tried

```
export http_proxy=localhost:8000
export https_proxy=localhost:8000
chromium
```

with no more result.

If I go to Chromium proxy settings `chrome://settings/system`, I get:

> When running Chromium under a supported desktop environment, the system proxy settings will be used. However, either your system is not supported or there was a problem launching your system configuration.
>
> But you can still configure via the command line. Please see man chromium for more information on flags and environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it, need a valid profile path:

```
chromium \
    --proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8888 \
    --user-data-dir=~/.config/chromium/proxy
```